# Why are these functions the same, but output a different value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a function to calculate the mean of a list, and excluding the zeroes, the `mean_val(`) is the function that should output `5.2200932159502855`, but instead it outputs `6.525116519937857` even though its the same formula.

The `mean_val2` function has the correct output: `5.2200932159502855` but this function doesn't exclude zeroes.

How do I make the `mean_val()` output `5.2200932159502855` while also excluding the zeroes from the list while also keeping it in this for loop format?

Here is the code + testing code:

```
val = [4, 3, 5, 0, 9, 3, 6, 0, 14, 15]
val1 = [4, 3, 5, 9, 3, 6, 14, 15]


def mean_val2(val1):    
    sum = 0
    for i in val1:
        print(i)
        sum += 1 / i  
        output = len(val1)/sum
    return output  
        
           
                
def mean_val(val): 
    sum = 0
    for i in val:
        if i != 0:  
            print(i)
            sum += 1 / i
            output2 = len(val)/sum  
    return output2
            
       
        
mean_out2 = mean_val2(val1) # 5.2200932159502855  correct output 
mean_out = mean_val(val) # 6.525116519937857
print (mean_out, mean_out2)
```

Comment: Your indentation is off. You meant to not indent: `outputx = len(valx)/sum`. The way you have it, the last time through the `for` loop the `outputx` is not updated.

Comment: @quamrana it still outputs the same, no difference.

Comment: Ok, but your indentation is still off. You have needless calculation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `len` of val and val1 are different.

`len(val)` is 10.

`len(val1)` is 8

When you divide `len/sum` you will get a different result.

You could add a counter to keep track of the length of the elements you do process:

```py
val = [4, 3, 5, 0, 9, 3, 6, 0, 14, 15]
val1 = [4, 3, 5, 9, 3, 6, 14, 15]


def mean_val2(val1_param):
    total = 0
    for i in val1_param:
        total += 1 / i
    output = len(val1_param) / total
    return output


def mean_val(val_param):
    total = 0
    non_zero_length = 0
    for i in val_param:
        if i != 0:
            total += 1 / i
            non_zero_length += 1
    output2 = non_zero_length / total
    return output2


mean_out2 = mean_val2(val1)
mean_out = mean_val(val)
print(mean_out, mean_out2)
print(mean_out == mean_out2)
```

Output:

```
5.2200932159502855 5.2200932159502855
True
```

---

General notes:

1. You shouldn't use variable name `sum` as it shadows the name of the built-in function [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). I changed it to total in the modified code.
2. Your function arguments should not have the same name as your lists defined in global scope. I added a `_param` suffix, but a more meaningful variable name would be better.

---

You could also reuse your functions. Instead of doing similar processing in both, you could instead filter out the 0s in your list and pass that to your `mean_val2` function

```py
def mean_val(val_param):
    return mean_val2([i for i in val_param if i != 0])


def mean_val2(val1_param):
    total = 0
    for i in val1_param:
        total += 1 / i
    output = len(val1_param) / total
    return output
```

---

As Comprehension:

```py
def mean_val(lst):
    # Filter Out 0 Elements From List
    return mean_val2([i for i in lst if i != 0])


def mean_val2(lst):
    # Process List with No Zeros
    return len(lst) / sum([1 / i for i in lst])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use one function for both lists:

```
val = [4, 3, 5, 0, 9, 3, 6, 0, 14, 15]
val1 = [4, 3, 5, 9, 3, 6, 14, 15]

            
def mean_val(val=[]) -> float: 
    sum_rec = 0
    zeros = 0
    for i in val:
        if i != 0:  
            print(i)
            sum_rec += 1 / i
        else:
            zeros += 1
    output2 = (len(val) - zeros) / sum_rec
    return output2
            
               
mean_out2 = mean_val(val1) # 5.2200932159502855  correct output 
mean_out = mean_val(val) # 5.2200932159502855  correct output
print (mean_out, mean_out2)
```